# CSS: How to style text in a box with a limited height

Tags: html, css

Have the following html that leverages Dust.js:

```
<div class="box">
    {text}
</div>
```

I want to style the `box` div such that, if the text, which is variable, goes longer than 100 pixels in height, it is cut off, so that the box works as a kind of mask for the text in question. Setting

```
.box{
   height: 100px;
}
```

does not do the trick here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.box{
    max-height: 100px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.box{
   max-height: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the term `max-height` with CSS3 and *maybe* `white-space:nowrap;`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `overflow:hidden`

see jsfiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/